# How to take Mule ESB into Microsoft Azure Cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, mule

I am looking forward to take Mule ESB server along with other web servers into Microsoft Azure Cloud. But it seems Mule ESB is not supported on Microsoft Azure.

So my question is:

**1) Is it true that "Mule ESB is not supported on Microsoft Azure"?**

**2) Is it supported on Amazon Cloud ?**

**3) What are the alternates if not Microsoft Azure?**

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Not that i'm aware of. This blog indicates its possible: http://blog.kloud.com.au/2015/02/16/mule-esb-devtest-environments-in-microsoft-azure/

2) Yes. There are many deployments of Mule ESB on EC2. In fact CLoudhub, Mule's IPaaS offering is built upon EC2.

3) There are many other platform providers that would support Mule, including Amazon EC2, Cloudhub, Openshift. Here is a list of supported Operating Systems or failing that supported Application servers for v3.6:
Source(https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Compatibility)

**Application Servers**

The current release of Mule ESB supports the following application servers:

Eclipse Jetty 8
JBoss 6.1 (Enterprise)
JBoss 7 (Community)
Apache Tomcat 7
IBM WebSphere 8
Oracle WebLogic 12c
Additionally, users have reported success deploying Mule ESB with the following application servers:

Geronimo

**Java Virtual Machines**

The current release of Mule ESB supports the following Java Virtual Machines:

Oracle Hot Spot 7
IBM JVM 7

**Operating Systems**

The current release of Mule ESB supports the following operating systems:

Ubuntu 14.04
Ubuntu Server 12.04.2
Red Hat RHEL 7
Red Hat RHEL 6.6
Red Hat RHEL 5.8
Oracle Solaris 11 (Solaris Sparc and Solaris Intel)
Raspberry Pi Raspbian raspberry 3.6.11 (Mule ESB EE only)
Apple Mac OS 10.9
Apple Mac OS 10.8
Apple Mac OS 10.7
IBM AIX 
HP HP-UX 11i V3
Microsoft Windows 7
Microsoft Window 2012 Server
Microsoft Windows 2008 Server